# Time constrained loop unit

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration

I have a particularly difficult loop, in that it consists of two variables looping and sowing the result if a criteria is met. 
Overall it works for me, but some certain values for my variables take extremely long to compute, whilst most others go through instantly.

I would thus like to apply a time constraint for every calculation in my loop, but instead of aborting, i'd like for the loop to just break and continue to the next iteration.

How would i do this if my code looks like so:

```
Reap[Do[Do[(g = i;
o = 1;
Kbt = 1;
a = j;
p := Solve[(s^2) + g*(s^a) + (o^2) == 0, s];
b = Abs[Re[s /. p[[1]]]];
ot = Abs[Im[s /. p[[1]]]];
fi = Pi + ArcTan[(-1)*(ot/b)];
v = 2 ot - ((g*a*Sin[(1 - a)*fi])/((b^2) + (ot^2))^((1 - a)/2));
u = -2 b + ((g*a*Cos[(1 - a)*fi])/((b^2) + (ot^2))^((1 - a)/2));
Om = ArcTan[u/v];
B[r_] := (a big function);
H[t_] := (a big function);
fm = FindMinValue[H[t], {t, 1, 10}]);
  If[fm >= 0, Sow[{a , g}]; Break[]], {i, 0, 5, 0.01}], {j, 0.44, 
   0.98, 0.01}]]
```

This code gives me a load of points which i want to graph (the criteria for each point is that it is positive in the interval 1-10, which i determine with FindMinValue on said interval). However having it take days because of some points that could easily be replaced with the next iteration or previous one, is a tad tedious.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you profiled which step exactly is taking that long? Blindly, you could try using `NSolve` or `FindRoot` instead of `Solve`. Also, loops may not be the best method to go about your problem, if expressed in *Mathematica*. Could you rewrite your algorithm as a `Table` and parallelize it, or use other vector (e.g. `Map`) approaches?

Comment: Table didnt work for me well. It didnt want to let my function through.. might try again though. 
About the step, its usually on computing H[t_] and can happen on seemingly random values, where the i and j happen to form particularly difficult expressions.
The way i do it now is evaluate only the center of my graphs points (the graph im expecting to get) and find the edges by hand, viewing graphs.

EDIT: Scrach that... NSolve for the fractional polynome helps ALOT... ill look into it

Comment: How about `TimeConstrained` with `CheckAbort`?  Example: `Do[
 CheckAbort[TimeConstrained[
   Pause[Mod[i, 3]];
   Print[i],
   1.5],
  Null
  ],
 {i, 10}
 ]`

Comment: EDIT2: WOW NSolve was the key... i somehow missed the impact of Solve... THANKS!
And ill check out the loop criteria too. It is still of interest to me on a larger scale

Comment: @Szabolcs That's a construct worthy to be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How about TimeConstrained with CheckAbort? Example: Do[ CheckAbort[TimeConstrained[ Pause[Mod[i, 3]]; Print[i], 1.5], Null ], {i, 10} ] – Szabolcs Nov 14 at 22:13

Thanks loads!